# Forest plot overlapping the text of figure

Tags: metafor

I am new doing the meta-analysis in metafor package, the forest plot is overlapping with the text of heterogenicity, how can I separate them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FkZj.png)

Comment: Here is my code:forest.meta(m1,
            layout = "JAMA",
            xlim = c(0, 1),
            digits.pval = 3,
            digits.pval.Q = 3,
            JAMA.pval = FALSE,
            print.tau2 = TRUE,
            zero.pval = TRUE,
            xlab = "Proportion \nIV, random (95% CI)",
            leftcols = c("studlab", "effect", "ci"),
            leftlabs = c("Study", "Proportion", "95% CI"),
            fontsize = 12,
            fontfamily = NULL,
            plotwidth = "5cm",
            colgap.forest.right = "5mm",
           )

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are using the `meta` package, not `metafor`.